# How to retrieve data correctly using jaxb and and rest api in Angular 5?

Tags: java, json, angular, rest, jaxb

I've implemented a service for the rest api and Angular component which call the service, the java rest api is working fine (returning results to the browser),
I am even able to see the results (array of elements) in the browser console of
the Angular application.
The problem is that I can't find way to access the data.[see angular app concole here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ3RD.png)

The java jaxb annotation add root level class name to the each one of the elements in the array (trip in this case).

So when I'm using *ngFor in the html it actually display 8 rows but the data for each row is empty. (the data is actually there).

The "Trip" prefix is good for xml conversion, but not for JSON format.

**Service method**

```
public getTrips: Observable<Trip[]> {
      return this.http.get<Trip[]>(this.myUrl);
    }
```

**The relevant part in the component**

```
myTrips: Trip[] = [];

  constructor(private tripService: TripService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTrips();
  }

  getTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTrips()
    .subscribe(
      data => { this.myTrips = data},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log(this.myTrips)
    );
  }
```

**Trip interface**

```
export interface Trip {
  description: string;
}
```

Is anyone have an idea what should be update in order to display the data in the page correctly {{trip.description}}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below changes

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of mytrips">
    <td>{{data.trip.description}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A minimum explanation will help to understand your code and why this is a solution to the asked question.

Comment: Your solution is working fine and prove that I need to send something else to the view (omit the trip prefix). I prefer to have in the view: let trip of mytrips.